# Plotting points in a series where x coordinate equals zero

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

When you have a line series where all the x-coordinates are zero, the chart helpfully re-organises the points so that the x-coordinates are 1, 2, 3 etc. That's fine but, in the case where I have only one point in the series and the x-coordinate of that point really is zero, I want to override this "helpful" behaviour so that the point is displayed at its genuine x-coordinate (ie 0.0), and not the substituted x-coordinate (ie 1.0).

Does anyone know how to do this? I suspect it's obvious when you know how.

**Edit 1**

Thanks jstreet. Your example is what I want, but when I run this code, I get this output! What could be different?

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].IsXValueIndexed= false;

    chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    chart1.Series["Series2"].IsXValueIndexed= false;

    chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.Point;
    chart1.Series["Series3"].IsXValueIndexed= false;

    chart1.Series["Series4"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.FastPoint;
    chart1.Series["Series4"].IsXValueIndexed= false;

    chart1.Series["Series5"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series["Series5"].IsXValueIndexed= true;

    chart1.Series["Series6"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    chart1.Series["Series6"].IsXValueIndexed= true;

    chart1.Series["Series7"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.Point;
    chart1.Series["Series7"].IsXValueIndexed= true;

    chart1.Series["Series8"].ChartType= SeriesChartType.FastPoint;
    chart1.Series["Series8"].IsXValueIndexed= true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(70, 80));
        chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(60, 70));
        chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(50, 60));
        chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(40, 50));
        chart1.Series["Series5"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(30, 40));
        chart1.Series["Series6"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(20, 30));
        chart1.Series["Series7"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(10, 20));
        chart1.Series["Series8"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(0, 10));
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

As requested...

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series7 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series8 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // chart1
    // 
    chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
    this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
    this.chart1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    legend1.Name = "Legend1";
    this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
    this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
    this.chart1.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.Chocolate;
    series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series1.Legend = "Legend1";
    series1.Name = "Series1";
    series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series2.Legend = "Legend1";
    series2.Name = "Series2";
    series3.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series3.Legend = "Legend1";
    series3.Name = "Series3";
    series4.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series4.Legend = "Legend1";
    series4.Name = "Series4";
    series5.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series5.Legend = "Legend1";
    series5.Name = "Series5";
    series6.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series6.Legend = "Legend1";
    series6.Name = "Series6";
    series7.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series7.Legend = "Legend1";
    series7.Name = "Series7";
    series8.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series8.Legend = "Legend1";
    series8.Name = "Series8";
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series3);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series4);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series5);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series6);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series7);
    this.chart1.Series.Add(series8);
    this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 397);
    this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
    // 
    // MainForm
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 397);
    this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
    this.Name = "MainForm";
    this.Text = "TestChart";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainFormLoad);
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I can reproduce the problem without overriding any defaults - adding one or more points to a `Point` `SeriesChartType`, all with zero for the X value. I can relieve the symptoms by adding a dummy point at `X != 0` and setting its `IsEmpty = true` to hide it but this seems like a very clumsy fix.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855348/incorrect-overriding-value-of-zero-valued-x-axes-in-mvc-chart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two y-values for x=0 in a MS Chart control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786931/plotting-two-y-values-for-x-0-in-a-ms-chart-control)

Answer (score 2):

`AddXY` always respects your wishes. If you make all points x=0, that's what you get:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i, r.Next(0, 50));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(0, r.Next(50, 100));

        chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Designer generated code:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
        this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // chart1
        // 
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        this.chart1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        legend1.Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
        legend1.Docking = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Top;
        legend1.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
        series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series1.Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle;
        series1.Name = "Series1";
        series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series2.Legend = "Legend1";
        series2.MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Square;
        series2.Name = "Series2";
        series3.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series3.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series3.Legend = "Legend1";
        series3.MarkerSize = 8;
        series3.MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Diamond;
        series3.Name = "Series3";
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series3);
        this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(782, 353);
        this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(782, 353);
        this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

Comment: This is not what I get!? See counter example

Comment: Are you using `ChartType.Line` ? Note there's a couple different line chart types. Also, you may have defined one chart using VS Designer and another one through code behind, so what you see may not correspond to your code.

Comment: Also, in your `Series`, `IsXValueIndexed` should be set to `False`. Try starting from a fresh `Chart`, without changing any of the standard properties and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks again. I am aware of this. My updated example shows results using various chart types with `IsXValueIndexed` set to `true` and `false`. What version are you using?

Comment: I was on 4.0 but upping it to 4.5.2 makes no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please post your `Form.Designer.cs`, specifically `InitializeComponent()` method.

Comment: Except for cosmetic things like color palette and marker style, I don't see any relevant difference... Check your `App.config` and make sure you're using .NET 4.5.2. It should show something like this: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />`

Comment: After that do a `Build/Clean Solution` and then `Build/Rebuild Solution`.

Comment: `App.config` checks out. I'm doubtful about hunting for more errors in my code because it does, after all, exhibit the documented, expected behaviour. What's curious is that your code seems to successfully override that behaviour, which is what I want to achieve. Is it possible for you to post your `InitializeComponent()` method, please?

Comment: `InitializeComponent()` posted.

Comment: OK I get the same result as you! It seems to be down to the fact that your `series1` has non-zero x-values. I need to do a comparison with my real-life code now, because I thought that also shared a chart with other series with non-zero x-values. Unfortunately that means I still have an unsolved problem because when I add my first point `AddXY(0.0, y)` it appears at `(1, y)` instead of `(0, y)`

Comment: I'm curious about it now...:O) What did you do to get the same result as mine?

Comment: I mean when I run your code here I get the same result as you. But if I plot your `series1` against `x=0` instead of `x=i` I get the same behaviour as my code.

Comment: Bizarre....:O) What do you get if you run "my code" with no modifications? Do you get all 3 series correctly?

Comment: Yes. As in your original example