# Incorrect/overriding value of zero-valued x-axes in MVC Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plot, charts, complex-numbers

I'm attempting to use the MVC .NET`Chart` type to plot a [constellation diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78056/constellations-in-digital-communication). 
This means (for a series of numbers) plotting the `real` part of each number on the *y* axis, and the `imaginary` part of each point on the *x* axis. This means you often have an entire data set with zero on the *x*-axis, if the sequence is completely real. For example;

```
int N = 10; //Set the number of points in chart
decimal[] yReal = new decimal[N]; //Allocate real & imag arrays
decimal[] yImag = new decimal[N]; 
//Allocate values into axes
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { yReal[i] = (decimal) i; yImag[i] = 0M;}

Chart TimeChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddSeries(chartType: "Point", xValue: yImag, yValues: yReal)
    .SetYAxis("Q (real)", Double.NaN)//Set axes & limits
    .SetXAxis("I (imaginary)", Double.NaN);
```

However, I have found, that if I input an array containing all zeros, rather than plotting all the values with zero as an x-value, it instead plots the values with their index number on the x-axis as shown below;[image: incorrect values]

My current fix is to instead use a very small number that is not considered zero by the `Chart.AddSeries` method, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { yReal[i] = (decimal) i; yImag[i] = 2e-16M;}
```

Which gives the desired plot below (where everything now correctly *appears* to have `x=0`) as shown below [image: correct image]

However, this would become more and more problematic if I was to plot smaller numbers, so I was wonderning what the reason for this behaviour is,
and what I can do to get around it?

Comment: This is an old and weird bug in the `Chart` control.
You need to add **one** **dummy** `DataPoint` that has an X-Value **different** from `0`. (No problem making it transparent)

Comment: The linked duplicate has nothing to do with this question. The correct duplicate question (with a good answer) is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786931